# Slim Framework simplexml_load_string parser error

Tags: php, xml, codificação-de-caracteres, slim, unicode

Minha aplicação envia uma string no formato XML para o servidor.

```
        $(function() {

        var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <note> <to>Tove</to> <from>Jani</from> <heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> </note>";
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
             data: { xml : xml},
             contentType: "application/xml; charset=UTF-8; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'http://www.e-sms.com.br/api',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (request){
                console.log(request);
            }
        });    
    });
    </script>
```

Obtenho o seguinte erro.

```
"<br /><b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\Request.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string(): xml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D'1.0'%20encoding%3D'UTF-8'%3F%3E%20%3Cnote%3E%20%3Cto% in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\Request.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\Request.php</b> on line <b>202</b><br /><br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unexpected data in output buffer. Maybe you have characters before an opening &lt;?php tag?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php:552Stack trace:#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(344): Slim\App-&gt;finalize(Object(Slim\Http\Response))#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(298): Slim\App-&gt;process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\lib\api\api.php(71): Slim\App-&gt;run()#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\lib\api\api.php(40): lib\api\api-&gt;create_routes()#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\lib\api\api.php(33): lib\api\api-&gt;initialize()#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\lib\api\api.php(76): lib\api\api-&gt;__construct()#6 {main}  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php</b> on line <b>552</b><br />"
```

O Framework Slim tem pouca documentação.
Vi algumas soluções que indicam usar uma extensão chamada Middleware.
Ele faz o parse.
Com o comando composer required slim/slim "^3.0" o middle já é instalado.
O app não consegue encontrar a classe ContentType.php.
Acredito que um recurso como o composer já deixa a aplicação com as dependências satisfeitas. Seguindo essa linha de raciocínio eu não me preocupo com isso.

A minha aplicação consegue transferir os dados utilizando

```
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8; charset=utf-8",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8; charset=utf-8"
```

o problema está com o XML.
Alguma ideia de como posso resolver isso ?

Answer (score -1):

Cara pelo visto você está passando o xml e o parser do slim não está entendo.
Imagino que o problema esteja aqui:

```
data: { xml : xml}
```

É pouco provável que o código acima envia um xml como string. Experimente apenas:

```
data: {xml}
```

Uma forma de verificar o que está chegando no servidor é você retornar o que foi enviado e ver nas ferramentas do navegador a resposta.